Reinstalling Python, R, MySQL, on other things on a computer that has been setup from the backup of another computer
I have a laptop that runs on Windows 11, that I setup with with files backed up to an external hard drive from a laptop that ran on Windows 10. I should note that the old laptop is/was on its last legs and the battery no longer acquires charge and it only works while plugged in to the charger, and frequently crashes due to overheating.
While all of my files were sucessfully restored (such as Microsoft Word, all of the various scripts I wrote in several programming languages, pictures, seemingly my iTunes library), several pieces of software did not make a complete transition, or a transition at all for some reason, despite being backed up. That is, there are icons on the desktop, but some of them just appear as a generic blank page instead of the proper graphic. Also, when I try to use them an error message pops up saying that the corresponding '.exe' file is missing from the C:\Program Files\ directory.
An additonal thing to note, my current laptop has a whole Onedrive thing, so when when the laptop was being setup from backup, for some reason, the folder listed documents there, is the Onedrive documents folder, the actual documents folder, and everything else restored from backup is located under "This PC", specifically "Local Disk (C:)". I don't know if this is relevant or not, but I thought I'd include this information for the sake of completeness.
Also, there are two "Program Files" folders, one just named "Program Files", the other named "Program Files (x86)". This is how it was on the old computer.
I have just backed up my computer to my second external hard drive as a precaution before I try anything. The backup was successful save for a single photo file that could not be found.
Ultimately, my I wish to avoid creating any duplicate files or losing any scripts when reinstalling everything. To give a quick overview of everything already on the computer, there is GitBash, Audacity, a folder titled RTools with associated files, R x64 3.6.1, and Ri386 3.6.1. The things that are either missing, or incomplete are Python, Atom, GitHub desktop, Adobe Acrobat, RStudio, DBBrowser (SQLite), DBBrowser (SQLCipher), Finale and associated Aria Player (included for completeness, just need to know if reinstalling from website will not result in duplicates), MuseScore (included for completeness, just need to know if reinstalling from website will not result in duplicates), GuitarPro7 (have disk for the software just need to know if I need to uninstall first or if I can just install using the disk without any issues with duplicate files), and iTunes (will contact Apple Support but any help is appreciated).
Can I simply install each of these the way I did originally without any issues with duplicates or will I need to do any kind of uninstallation. If the latter is necessary, what do I need to double-check in terms of directory location, etc. to make sure things like my scripts or GuitarPro compositions don't get lost (just being paranoid here)?
Sorry for the long, rambly post, but this has been giving me a lot of anxiety. Thanks for reading through all of this!
